# Task 'jacoocoTestReport' not found in root project

Tags: java, gradle, junit, jacoco

I'm trying to find out the line coverage of the JUnit tests in my java program by using gradle and jacoco but the following command causes a failure.

```
gradle test jacoocoTestReport
```

The command prints:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task 'jacoocoTestReport' not found in root project 'ProjectName'. Some candidates are: 'jacocoTestReport'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with
    --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with                                           
    --info                                                                          
    or                                                                            
    --debug                                                                         
    option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.389 secs
```

The build.gradle of my gradle project:

```
apply plugin: "jacoco"

apply plugin: 'java'

apply plugin: 'application'

repositories {
   jcenter()
}

dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.guava:guava:20.0'  
   testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

mainClassName = 'example.Main'

run {
   standardInput = System.in
}

jacocoTestReport {
   reports {
      xml.enabled = true
      html.enabled = true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: use

> jacocoTestReport

instead of

> jacoocoTestReport

(two o's).

Use

> gradle tasks

to check what tasks are defined.

Comment: I am also getting same error when I use `gradlew test jacocoTestReport`

Comment: I am still getting the same error `Task 'jacocoTestReport' not found in root project 'MyTestingProject'`. And Command-> `gradle tasks` not showing Task `jacocoTestReport`. Can someone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: @Kavita_p Ask a new question, and include your `build.gradle`. See also [ask].

Comment: Yes, sure @Robert

Answer (score 1):

You've run an invalid task (double *o*):

```
gradle test jacoocoTestReport
```

instead of:

```
gradle test jacocoTestReport
```